# What is the intuition of summing the off diagonals of a matrix, in comparison to the formula for the determinant, and separately, the trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The determinant of a 2x2 matrix can be calculated by multiplying the components of the main diagonal, and subtracting the product of the off-diagonal.

The trace is found by summing the components of the main diagonal.

I have encountered a formula that involves summing the main diagonal, and subtracting the sum of the off diagonal. This seems to closely represents the formula for the determinant of a 2x2 matrix as well as the formula for the trace.

Is this "called" something, or connected to these two concepts in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important properties of the determinant and the trace is invariance under conjugation, meaning that for any invertible matrix $Q$, and any matrix $A$, we have
$$ \mathrm{trace}(QAQ^{-1}) = \mathrm{tr}(A)$$
and
$$ \det(Q A Q^{-1}) = \det(A)$$

If we try out your function $f$,
$$ f \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = (a + d) - (b + c)$$
we can see that it is not preserved under conjugation, since for example
$$ f \left( \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) = f \begin{pmatrix} a & b/2 \\ 2c & d \end{pmatrix} = (a + d) - (b/2 + 2c)$$
so I think this function $f$ probably is not related to the trace or the determinant in an obvious way, and certainly not a "natural" one.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks!